# How can i pull a user's facebook status message using the Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've tried to use this method using the Graph API, but it doesn't return the status messages ... Is there anyway I can pull those ?  How can I also get the feeds of the Facebook pages that a user's follow .. Like for example coca cola's page .. how can I retrieve its feeds if I like it ??  answers would be appreciated !!!

```
$status = $facebook->api("/690196511");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php

$facebook_appid         = "facebook_appid";                                 // Facebook appplication id
$facebook_secret        = "facebook_secret";                // Facebook secret id
$facebook_pageid        = "facebook_pageid";                                // Facebook secret id
$redirect_uri           = "https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
//$redirect_uri         = "https://localhost/facebook_page/fb_login.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
$scope                  = "user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_stream,user_events,friends_events"; // User permission for facebook


$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"]?$_REQUEST["code"]:"";

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state']  = time(); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url         = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&state=". $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$scope;
    header("location:".$dialog_url);
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] == $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url          = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri). "&client_secret=" . $facebook_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response           = @file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params             = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $account_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_pageid."?fields=access_token&access_token=".$params['access_token'];
    $resp               = @file_get_contents($account_url);

    $dt                 =   json_decode($resp);


    echo $dt->access_token;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dt->id;

    $offer_url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$dt->id."/feed?access_token=".$dt->access_token;
    $off                = @file_get_contents($offer_url);
    $dto                = json_decode($off);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dto);


}

?>
```